# Wkhtmltopdf in aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying the sample on https://www.drivenbycode.com/creating-pdfs-from-html-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway/

I am stuck in test. When I make the test run I get an error like this:

```
    Execution result: failed(logs)
Details
The area below shows the result returned by your function execution. Learn more about returning results from your function.
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: e518cd5c-2ee0-11e8-9af4-abd55dea481f Process exited before completing request"
}
Summary

Code SHA-256
kFqfcOZdsw5hmmn2VZ62QVULXrwqdh3jMDh90EJR4gI=
Request ID
e518cd5c-2ee0-11e8-9af4-abd55dea481f
Duration
1383.09 ms
Billed duration
1400 ms
Resources configured
128 MB
Max memory used
40 MB
Log output
The area below shows the logging calls in your code. These correspond to a single row within the CloudWatch log group corresponding to this Lambda function. Click here to view the CloudWatch log group.
START RequestId: e518cd5c-2ee0-11e8-9af4-abd55dea481f Version: $LATEST
2018-03-23T21:26:49.954Z    e518cd5c-2ee0-11e8-9af4-abd55dea481f    TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
    at Response.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:25:45)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:364:18)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
END RequestId: e518cd5c-2ee0-11e8-9af4-abd55dea481f
REPORT RequestId: e518cd5c-2ee0-11e8-9af4-abd55dea481f  Duration: 1383.09 ms    Billed Duration: 1400 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 40 MB  
RequestId: e518cd5c-2ee0-11e8-9af4-abd55dea481f Process exited before completing request
```

I have prepared the the index file as requested. The only change I made was the name of the bucket.

When the test run exits, it creates a test.pdf in the correct bucket, but with the following content:

```
AccessDeniedAccess DeniedA6FF69637CAFDA68RjoN8UiT+V5MzrWN0G4h3SeIKgdu6eybNCtQMf+h+x5WxFwI1OyvF0Z2K6fhMP0RRn3RtStEKps=
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: URL to the tutorial is broken but I was able to find it on [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170219010233/https://www.drivenbycode.com/creating-pdfs-from-html-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway/)

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like your pdf var is undefined.

I ran into this problem when following the same guide.

It is because you have not included the `wkhtmltopdf` binary in your lambda function project root.

At this point you have two options. You can build the binary in an Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance yourself, which I hear is a pain or grab the binary from someone else I can't recommend this if it is from an unofficial source, however, you can find version 12.4 (current version is 12.5 as of this writing) [here](https://github.com/dimiro1/lambda-wkhtmltopdf).

If you want to go the route of building it yourself, AWS Lambda runs on Amazon Linux AMI, you can find the current version [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html). (More [info](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/) on running executables in AWS Lambda).

Once you have a binary, include it in your project root and make sure it is executable, `chmod +x wkhtmltopdf`.

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this.

Other useful links:

- [wkhtmltopdf official download page](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)
- [wkhtmltopdf github repo](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf)

The `AccessDeniedAccess` error occurs because the bucket and its contents are not public. To download the file as an authorized user you have to download the file through the file's properties menu in the aws console, not by trying to access the link.
[S3 download guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/download-objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use a suitable version of wkhtmltopdf.sh file. lambda supports 64 bit binary file (only 64 bit).